# How to force style HTML element?

Tags: html, css

I want to place my button in the lower right corner.

Here's what I have tried:

- I tried use `!important`, but it had no effect

CSS:

```
#back-to-top {
    position: fixed !important;
    right:400 !important;
    bottom: 17!important;
    color: black;
    border: #90bc26 solid 1px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Here is what I see when inspecting my button:

[image]

As you can see, my `right`, and `bottom` style got overridden, how do I fix that?

Comment: your right and bottom properties need units like `400px` or `400em`. only 0 doesn't need units

Comment: Those exclamation icons probably says something useful

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forgot to use measurement unit like `px`, `%` or `em` for right and bottom:

```
right:400px;
bottom: 17px;
```

No need to use `!important`.

Answer (score -2):

Change your css selectors from

```
#idname
```

to

```
tag#idname
```

So your selector would be something like

```
button#back-to-top
```

Comment: Paste experience I've had.  Sometimes I'd use selectors that weren't as precise in their targets as other selectors, and the attributes would be overwritten.  And this has happened on a few occasions against the ids of tags.